# Возможно ли как-нибудь сократить код?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, не важно какая, главное, что в ней есть условие `if (a>b)` : см.

```
function ab(x) {
    var a, b;
    if (a > b) {
        // блок кода
    }
    if (a < b) {
        // тот же самый блок кода
    }
}
```

Смысл в том, чтобы не копировать один и тот же кусок кода по 10 раз. Это возможно ли как-нибудь сократить?

Comment: я этого и хочу достичь

Comment: Что-бы этого достичь нужно видеть весь код, а не то, что предоставили вы

Comment: читайте комменты ответа AlexWindHope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.

```
var ALowerThenB = a > b;
if( ALowerThenB ) {/* code */}
if( ALowerThenB ) {/* code */}
```

А вообще, если это возможно - лучше всего продумать код так, что-бы поместить всю логику в 1о условие.

Возможно вы имели введу это:

```
function someFunc() {
    var a,b;
    // если кода много - можно сделать функцией, что-то типа
    function test(){
        if( a < b ) {
            // тут много много вашего кода
        }
    }
    // соответственно вызов сводиться к вызову функции
    test();
}
```

Comment: вот это уже более подходящий вариант

Comment: если интересно, немного jsfiddle, это я сортировку массива хочу немного разнообразить, чтобы не только по возр., но и по убыванию было, правда еще 1-ну переменную нужно добавить на вход функции, но пока так: http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/h4fNN/2/

Comment: Если правильно понял - добавьте вызов прототипного метода reverse, для результата работы функции и будет вам счастье.

     [1,2,3,4,5].reverse(); // -> [5,4,3,2,1]

Comment: а это разве стандартная функция?

Comment: Вот именно, [пруф](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)

Comment: тогда это все меняет, спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/h4fNN/4/ ЛОГИЧНО?

Comment: И для сортировки можете юзать метод sort, грубо говоря все что вы писали можно написать так:

    function sorted( arr, reverse ) {
       var res = arr.sort();
       return reverse !== undefined ? res.reverse() : res;
    }
    // или вообще так
    function sorted( arr, reverse ) {
       return reverse !== undefined ? arr.sort().reverse() : arr.sort()
    }

Вот это действительно логично :D

Comment: Еще непосредственно к вопросу, можно сделать что-то типа:

    var lowerFunction = function(){/* code */};
    var higherFunction = function(){/* code */};
    a < b ? lowerFunction() : higherFunction();

Comment: вместо ``reverse()`` можно передать в ``sort()`` компаратор.
``arr.sort(function(a,b){return (a-b)*direction;})``, где direction - направление сортировки (1 или -1). В случае более сложной сортировки будет проще вносить изменения, кроме того массив сразу будет сортироваться в нужном направлении, без дополнительного "перевертывания".

Answer (score 5):

Возможно я чего то не понимаю, но 2 условия: a>b и a<b

можно записать:

```
function ab(x){
    var a,b;
    if (a != b) {
       // блок кода
    }
}
```

Если же вы привели это просто для иллюстрации, то воспользуйтесь вариантом: [[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope) т.е через функцию.

Comment: ну вы тоже в чем-то правы, но в моей глобальной задаче это не подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал так:

```
function ab(x) {
  function _ab() {
    // блок кода
  }

  var a,b;
  if (a>b)
    _ab();
  if (a<b)
    _ab();
}
```

Comment: вполне это тоже о чем я думал, но получилось еще проще.

Answer (score 0):

**Ну и как же без меня:**D

```
function ab(x) {
    var a, b;
    function c() {
        return true;
    }
    a>b&&c(); 
    a<b&&c();
}
```

Comment: a>b&&c();  
это даже извращеннее, чем (a<b)?1:0 у меня вчера )

Comment: @ReinRaus, в чем извращение?

Comment: Наверно в плохой читаемости конструкции. Нужно помнить, что сначала будет выполнена операция сравнения, а потом &&, также надо знать, что если левая часть && имеет значение false, то правая часть проверяться не будет (и это не нечто само-собой разумеющееся- в некоторых языках всегда выполняются обе части операнда).

Comment: @ReinRaus, всё там правильно.

Comment: А почему функция c() описана с одним параметром, а вызывается без него? @ReinRaus идиома для таких языков обычная. В perl'е постоянно `do_some_thing or die()`

Comment: @alexlz, специально, иначе JavaScript не может работать.

Comment: Совсем не понимаю. Было `function c(y)`, стало `function c()`, как не может работать javascript? (Вопрос был риторическим)